# The difference between during a week and during the week

Tags: time-words

I thought that: "During a week" means any week and "During the week" means a specific week.

> 1) What do you eat during a week? - (*every week*)
>   2) What do you eat during the week you spend in Spain every year?

However, it seems to me that some people use "during the week" to mean "during a week".

Is it possible for "during the week" to mean "any week"?

Answer (score 2):

The can also be used to represent the entire class.

> The cow is a domestic animal.
>   A cow is a domestic animal.

In the first sentence **the** represents the entire class whereas in the second one **a** is used to mean any.

Therefore the sentence

> What do you eat during the week?

Can also mean during every week

Comment: That's what I also thought. So, you think that "What do you eat during the week?" equals with "What do you eat during a week?"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you mentioned that you think is correct. "**The**" article is used to point out a specific week while **"A"** is used for any week.  [(Source)](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/articles.html).
"During the week" can not mean "during any week".

Comment: Have a look https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453165/does-it-sound-weird-if-i-say-i-do-do-sports-during-the-week It seems to me that people in that thread take "during the week" as "every/any week".